# If a file is created by 'open' but without a 'mode' specified, what will the mode be?

Tags: linux, file, unix

I try to create a file "foo" in current dir like this:

open("foo", O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR);

I did not give it a 'mode' for the third parameter, so what will it be?
On my ubuntu 14.04, the mode for the this new file seems to be a random value.
Isn't there any default value for the 'mode'?

Comment: What does the documentation tell you?

Comment: `man umask` or `help umask`

Comment: @rodrigo's answer seems reasonable, THX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the POSIX `man 3p open` it is not said very clearly, but in the Linux `man 2 open`:

```
int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

> **`mode`** specifies the permissions to use in case a new file is created.  This argument **must** be supplied when `O_CREAT` or `O_TMPFILE` is  specified in  flags.

That is, if `mode` is not supplied when it should, the results are **undefined**.

Comment: In other words: `open()` is a varargs-function.

Comment: @wildplasser: Yes, the POSIX man page says `int open(const char *path, int oflag, ...);`, but anything other than the two from Linux would be undefined. A bad idea from the beginning, if you ask me...